# App Crashes on launch when reading a file in assets

Tags: java, android, json, file

I am trying to recieve a JSON string from a file  in my assets folder, however shortly after the app opens it crashes with the following logcat

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ashb.osrstimers/com.ashb.osrstimers.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 10303 on device 'huawei-mar_lx1a-JRQDU20512003719'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
I/ashb.osrstimer: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
    QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
    QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/com.ashb.osrstimers
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
    QarthPatchMonintor::Run
I/ashb.osrstimer: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
I/ashb.osrstimer: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
    QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.ashb.osrstimers#10247#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.ashb.osrstimers#10247#0
I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:com.ashb.osrstimers pid=10303 uid=10247
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@5e2870f
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@b34439c
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=10303
```

The error seems to show  on these lines:

```
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@5e2870f
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@b34439c
```

Here is my code to read the data from the json file:

```
private String getJSONData() {
        String json_string;

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream input;

        try {
            input = assetManager.open("timers.json");
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            json_string = new String(buffer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json_string;
    }
```

Comment: "it crashes with the following logcat" -- there is no evidence there of a crash. "The error seems to show on these lines" -- that is not a stack trace, which would be evidence of a crash.

Comment: well the app crashes and that is all that shows

Comment: How are you determining that the app crashes? If you turn off filtering by process in Logcat, do you see a likely stack trace?

Comment: nothing that I can see

Comment: if readFileLines is a function then why did you call it?

Comment: `input.read(buffer);` Check if all is read: `int nread = input.read(buffer);` And make a loop if not all is read.